# jsTree addClass isn't remembered in some instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

Using jsTree and the drag and drop plugin, I'm trying to illustrate when a node's position has been changed.
Using the `move_node.jstree` event, I add a class of `isChanged` to the node that is moved and this works fine. However, if I move a node that is a sibling of one that has already been moved, the previously moved item has its `isChanged` class stripped.

Is there a way I can preserve the `isChanged` class on all moved nodes?

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/9e3vdn0y/)

*(Move the nodes on the same branch; only one with have the `isChanged` class)*

Here is the code for completeness:

```
$('#treeView').jstree({
    "core": {
        "check_callback": true
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
})
.on('move_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    
    $("#" + data.node.a_attr.id).addClass("isChanged");
    
    console.log(data.node.a_attr.id);
    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to persist the class you also need to add it to the internal jsTree representation of the node, otherwise the class will be lost when the node is redrawn.

```
.on('move_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $("#" + data.node.a_attr.id).addClass("isChanged");
    if(data.node.a_attr.class) {
      if(data.node.a_attr.class.indexOf('isChanged') === -1) {
        data.node.a_attr.class += ' isChanged';
      }
    }
    else {
      data.node.a_attr.class = 'isChanged';
    }   
    console.log(data.node.a_attr.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @vakata I get the following error though because `class` isn't a property of `li_attr`? **Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined** The error can be seen in this version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/9e3vdn0y/4/

Comment: I just edited my answer - sorry about omitting the check. I also did not see you were trying to update the class on the anchor element, not the list-item one. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9e3vdn0y/5/